# Is it necessary to call Popen.wait() to "clean up" after the Popen object?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am using `Popen` to maintain a pool of subprocesses in a Python program.  There are natural points in my program to perform "cleanup" - at these points I call `Popen.poll()` to determine whether a particular process is still running, and if not, I remove its `Popen` object from the pool and reclaim whatever resources it was using.

Is there any need to call `Popen.wait()` in order to perform some kind of language or OS level cleanup?  The call to `Popen.poll()` has already determined that the process has terminated, and it even sets the `returncode` attribute.  Is there any additional reason to call `Popen.wait()` as well?

Comment: The important part is `it even sets the returncode attribute.` This means that the subprocess was *already* terminated by the OS, and the OS has *already* done clean-ups on its resources/files etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you don't have to call `wait` if you are calling `poll`. They basically do the same thing, except that `wait` waits infinitely.

`poll`:

```
if self.returncode is None:
    if _WaitForSingleObject(self._handle, 0) == _WAIT_OBJECT_0:
        self.returncode = _GetExitCodeProcess(self._handle)
    return self.returncode
```

`wait`:

```
if self.returncode is None:
    _subprocess.WaitForSingleObject(self._handle,
                                    _subprocess.INFINITE)
    self.returncode = _subprocess.GetExitCodeProcess(self._handle)
return self.returncode
```

This is the code for windows implementation of the `subprocess` module, but all other should follow the same rules.

On MacOS X and I assume the implementation for Linux is the same, they both call `os.waitpid`.